# Read from XML over Http

Tags: java, xml, http

I am trying to learn how to read from an XML file (getting it from a url) over Http in Java and am pretty confused as to where I should start. I know how to parse an XML document and print the text associated with the elements to the screen and basic manipulation like that but I am trying to take it a little further.

If anyone could provide me with somewhere to start or any tips that would be much appreciated. I would be more than happy to provide more specifics if that is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Then provide more specifics, because they are needed. What exactly do you want to do and why doesn't it work?

Comment: apache commons httpclient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you already know how to deal with XML, you're just asking how to get the XML over HTTP.  This code should work.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(urlThatReturnsXml).openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
String responseAsString = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `java.net.URL` object from the url string and call [`openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) on it. You now have an InputStream to read from. That should get you going.